# Amazon Web Services Elastic Beanstalk Wordpress config file download lacks efs-create.config

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Reference AWS' "Deploying a High-Availability WordPress Website with an External Amazon RDS Database to Elastic Beanstalk" (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-hawordpress-tutorial.html#php-hawordpress-tutorial-launch)

When I downloaded the AWS Elastic Beanstalk configuration files for Wordpress (https://github.com/awslabs/eb-php-wordpress/releases/download/v1.0/eb-php-wordpress-v1), I do not see all the files referenced in the AWS instructions.  Specifically, I only see "license", "readme.md", and "wp-config.php".  However, the instructions reference "efs-create.config" and "dev.config".

All of the instructions thus far have been very detailed and step-by-step, so I'm not sure if I missed something - is the Elastic Beanstalk Command Line Interface (CLI) required to perform these actions?  I'm running OS X ver. 10.11.6.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EB either from Console or CLI .

Here you are using eb-php-wordpress (https://github.com/awslabs/eb-php-wordpress/) to provision your EB Environment like VPC, ELB, EC2,RDS. you will have to use the CLI .

Download Wordpress and navigate to wordpress directory .

Download the configuration file inside it . 
wget https://github.com/awslabs/eb-php-wordpress/releases/download/v1.0/eb-php-wordpress-v1.zip

Refer to README.md , everything is well explained .